# MinionPro % character not being properly rendered

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, installing, ubuntu

After installing MinionPro following instructions from https://toihoctap.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/install-minionpro-font-for-texlive-2012-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/ % signs aren't being properly rendered, as picture shows.

[image: % sign not showing properly]

Versions being used: Ubuntu 14.04, pdftex 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 and TexLive 2013/Debian.

Any ideas on how to fix this or where is the mistake I've made?